# CSP nonce with PUG and nodejs

Tags: node.js, pug, content-security-policy, helmet.js

I have been reading everything I can find about CSP, Helmet, nodejs, PUG. But I don't understand well, and what I am doing does not work.

In my PUG file for the login page (page source seems OK) I have

```
  script(nonce="e33ccde670f149c1789b1e1e113b0916").
    function populate() {
        var dbn = document.getElementById("dbname").value;
        var schem = document.getElementById("dbschema").value;
        var nom = document.getElementById("nomuser").value.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        document.getElementById("username").value = dbn + "_" + schem + "_" + nom;
    }
    function valid() {}
```

I have seen that I should use Helmet, and in the docs of Helmet I see this code that I put in my in my app.js

```
// Sets "Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self';script-src 'self' 'nonce-e33ccde670f149c1789b1e1e113b0916'"
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.cspNonce = 'e33ccde670f149c1789b1e1e113b0916';
    next();
  });
  app.use(
    helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
     directives: {
     defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
     scriptSrc: ["'self'", (req, res) => `'nonce-${res.locals.cspNonce}'`]
     }
   })
  );
```

It is not working. and in the console I have

```
   Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security 
   Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-e33ccde670f149c1789b1e1e113b0916'". Either 
   the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256o1i9bymuZKyWf/wjjYx0vr3nBkeKDiu6QOw0TLT8nTI='), 
    or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

I don't understand at all - complete blank in my head.
Any pointers at documents or examples or explanation would be really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Maintainer of Helmet here. First of all, for security, you should generate a new CSP nonce each time (but that doesn't seem to be your problem). Second, I don't see any problem with your code. You could check (1) if that header is actually set as you expect (2) if the nonce in the header matches the nonce in the HTML (3) if there's another `<script>` on the page that's causing this error.

Comment: Thank you - if my code is correct, then I can look at what else is causing problem. I found some library also giving the error. Of course I will generate the CSP, but wanted to begin with one less thing to check.  Thanks also for Helmet